# Subversion Ant update task taking forever

Tags: svn, ant, build-process, build-automation, performance

I've downloaded the svntask for ant from tigris.org, so it is the "official" one.

I have a simple task to update my entire project

```
<target name="prepare">
    <svn username="user" password="pass">
        <update>                
            <fileset dir="."/>
        </update>
    </svn>
</target>
```

Running this task took about 2 hours.

Running a `svn update` on the command line took about 5 seconds.

(in both cases, there were no updates to bring down from the server)

I've also tried chaning the method that svntask uses to interface with subversion, I've tried both the svnkit method and the command line method.

Any ideas why this may be taking so long?  Obviously this is unacceptably slow.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using the nested `<fileset>` the command ends up calling `update` for every file in the current directory hierarchy.  That's probably why it takes two hours.

Try using the `dir` attribute of the `update` task:

```
    <svn username="user" password="pass">
        <update dir="."/>                                
    </svn>
```

And, if that doesn't work, turn on `-verbose` or `-debug` and see if you can get more information about what is happening during the task.

Answer (score 1):

1.Which lib are you using for accessing to svn (svnkit or javahl)?

Try to explicitly provide an appropriate library:

```
<svn username="user" password="pass" svnkit="true">
```

2.I'm not sure if you have to provide username and password params for an update (their were cached on checkout).

3.If your use case are similar to mine, you can reuse **checkout** task for both *checkout* and an *update*:

```
<target name="prepare">
  <svn username="user" password="pass">
      <checkout url="${svn.url}" destpath="${svn.path}" />
    </svn>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you just run "ant prepare" it takes 2 hrs?  Or is this 2 hr duration only under special conditions like your build machine?

Have you tried using the  task for comparison, to try and isolate if it is Ant vs. the particular task?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why it would take 2 hours for the svntask, so I would first look into this in more details.

But if you must, you could run SVN from the command line:

```
<exec executable="cmd.exe">
    <arg line="/c svn checkout repository ..."/>
</exec>
```

Edit: Actually, you don't need the dos window, you can do it directly. I just do this so I can see the output in the ant console.

Answer (score 0):

It might be instructive to profile your build to see where it's actually spending most of its time.  [antutility](https://antutility.dev.java.net/) is very easy to use for this purpose.   Just add the jar to your classpath and run it like:

```
  ant -listener net.java.antutility.BuildMetricsListener [target]
```